# my issue by sending email with smtp server in joomla1.5?

Tags: joomla, smtp, gmail, sendmail

**background**

I have a Joomla 1.5 site, for registering user in site to enable the email sending system's, configured the smtp server in joomla configuration.
my config is:

```
mailer:'smtp server'
smtp host:'smtp.gmail.com'
smtp user:'myuser@gmail.com'
smtp psw:'mypass'
smtp port:'465' 
smtp authentication:'yes'
smtp security:'ssl'
```

I don't know becuase does not Work and it is worth noting that php mail function dosen't work!

Answer (score 1):

This is Answer Of Question:
I'm use the free-hosting and the hosting company **block the many php functions**.
One of the  php functions is **fsockopen** that socket to smtp server to connect them.

I hope this experiment help my friends.

Answer (score 0):

uncomment "extension=php_openssl.dll" in your php.ini file

add exception for port 465

Comment: in my host i haven't access to php configs!

Answer (score 0):

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

is used for windows hosting only, and most probably you will be using linux hosting so you don't need to worry about it.

I had a similar issue like yours and it turned out that the php function that I wrote in a script was not using smtp set in Joomla configuration, to confirm try using password reset or some other function that uses email from Joomla framework, and if you get that email successfully that would mean that your php email function is not using smtp.